# Why my apps give error when I am using scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

What is the matter here?
when I add scroll view here my apps give error. I have to put below and out of the scrollview my webview code and my back(geri) button. but my apps not work. when I remove scrollview then my apps work again

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <Button
         android:id="@+id/bn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="bn" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/deneme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="deneme" />
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/denemeiki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="denemeiki" />
</ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/geri"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="geri"
         />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show error please.

Comment: Have you initialized correctly the components?

Comment: no my emulator dont work. " unfortunately my apps stopped"  give me this error ı use android studio 3.0

Comment: scrollview can only host one direct child, please correct it wrap buttons into single layout

Answer (score 3):

scroll view can only contain only one child view.so you have to put the views into a relative layout or linear layout or something else and then put this relative layout in scroll view.

Comment: OK How can ı put below my "geri"  back button?

Comment: you want to put scroll view below of “geri” back button .am i right ?

Comment: ı want to put my back button on uı screen. ı want to show my back button everytime my screen bottom and rigth it is possible?